# Textarea doesn't resize properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was making a function to auto resize a `<textarea>` with jQuery. You can try the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('textarea').autoresize()
})

$.fn.autoresize = function(minRows=1, maxRows=5) {
  var e = $(this)
  e.attr('rows', minRows).css({'resize':'none'}).on('input', function(){ resize(e) })

  var state = 0
  function resize(e) {
    if (e.attr('rows') <= maxRows) {
      e.attr('overflow', 'hidden')
      if (e[0].scrollHeight>e.innerHeight() && e.attr('rows') < maxRows) {
        e.attr('rows', +e.attr('rows')+1)

        if (state) {
          state = 2
        }

        resize(e)
      } else if (e.attr('rows') > minRows) {
        if (state == 2) {
          state = 0
        } else {
          state = 1
          e.attr('rows', +e.attr('rows')-1)
          resize(e)
        }
      }
    } else {
      e.attr('overflow', 'auto')
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea style="width: 200px"></textarea>
```

If you type on the first row, the `<textarea>` will add a new row when its value needs to be overflowed. But when you type on the second row and so on, `<textarea>` will  add a new row even if it doesn't have to be overflowed.

At first I thought it's because the scrollbar, but I already set the `overflow` to `hidden` and it will only change to `overflow: scroll` when `<textarea>` rows equal to `maxRows`.

Comment: Voted to close as a _a problem that can no longer be reproduced_ given OP assign a style as an attribute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Accidentally, I set the `overflow` to `hidden` as an attribute, not a style.
So this one `e.attr('overflow', 'hidden')` should be `e.css('overflow', 'hidden')`

Here is the working code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autoresize()
  })

  $.fn.autoresize = function(minRows=1, maxRows=5) {
    var e = $(this)
    e.attr('rows', minRows).css({'resize':'none'}).on('input', function(){ resize(e) })

    var state = 0
    function resize(e) {
      if (e.attr('rows') <= maxRows) {
        e.css('overflow', 'hidden')
        if (e[0].scrollHeight>e.innerHeight() && e.attr('rows') < maxRows) {
          e.attr('rows', +e.attr('rows')+1)

          if (state) {
            state = 2
          }

          resize(e)
        } else if (e.attr('rows') > minRows) {
          if (e.attr('rows') == maxRows && e[0].scrollHeight>e.innerHeight()) {
            e.css('overflow', 'auto')
          }

          if (state == 2) {
            state = 0
          } else {
            state = 1
            e.attr('rows', minRows)
            resize(e)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea style="width: 200px"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -2):

something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#text").focus(function() {
    $("#text").attr("row", "10");
    $("#text").attr("style", "width: 100px");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" style="width: 200px" row="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: did you meant I need to `focus()` the textarea first before removing a row ?

Comment: it do not remove the row attribute, it just change the attribute row value when user focus on input, it's just an example, you can set css class and everything by this method

Comment: If you're going to use a snippet - please make it runable, otherwise use code tags/indent only

Comment: Did you mean `.attr("rows"` ?

Comment: @OtávioBarreto please check again my question

Comment: This could do with an explanation as to how it solve's OP problem.  Hint: it doesn't, it provides an alternative UX, which, in itself, is a valid answer - but needs an explanation as to why it's a valid alternative.  Otherwise it just looks like a failed answer as it doesn't solve the requested problem directly.

Comment: Please use the snippet editor correctly - `<script>` is not a valid javascript